# Enabling/disabling components over reboot

Tags: android

When you enable or disable a component in Android, is the state persistent over reboot or not? This behavior is not documented.

Comment: What do you mean by "component"?

Comment: @LukasKnuth  broadcast receiver for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the enabled state persists across a reboot.

One specific use of this feature is for conditionally enabling an `ACTION_BOOT_RECEIVED` receiver. Sometimes, you *may* need to get control at boot time, but not all the time. For example, if your app needs to download a large file, you might want to get control on a reboot in case the phone reboots while the download is in progress, so you can try again. But otherwise — such as after the download is completed — you do not need to get control at boot time. In that case, have the `ACTION_BOOT_RECEIVED` receiver disabled at the outset, enable it when the download starts, and disable it again when the download finishes. That way, most of the time, you aren't wasting the user's time at reboot, but you have it when you need it.

Comment: What about services that are started sticky? Any sources on what you're saying?

Comment: @LukasKnuth: "What about services that are started sticky?" -- if you mean "does the stickiness survive a reboot", I am not aware that it does. "Any sources on what you're saying?" -- besides good old-fashioned actually using the technique? No, though I seem to recall the idea coming from a Googler (blog post? I|O presentation?).

Comment: I mean it more like "are services automatically started after the reboot".

Comment: @LukasKnuth: No, they are not automatically started after the reboot, though I have not re-checked that behavior on Android 5.0 (which, given persistent tasks, still probably does not restart services, but it's not out of the question...).

Comment: ok, thanks. Probably best not to rely on this anyways and manually start services where and when they're needed.